# how can i get the install path from yum?

Tags: yum, centos5, paths

i install several application using yum in CentOS
now i like to see the installed application path's
where each component yum downloaded got installed
how can i do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rpm -ql PACKAGE_NAME` or `rpm -qpl /path/to/RPM/file` to get the paths to all the files and directories that are managed by the RPM.  If you're looking for the actual RPMs it downloaded, I believe it puts the download RPM's into `/var/cache/yum/*.rpm`.

Comment: Wrong on the path, but the rest is correct.

Comment: Ignacio, if you know the default path offhand, can you add it?  I'll be happy to correct the answer.  I don't run RPM-based distro at home, and I didn't feel like logging into my work computers to check.

Comment: The yum cache is under `/var/cache/yum`. The packages will only be retained if the yum configuration states that they should be.